# Access flash with h:link in JSF

Tags: jsf, el

When I'm about to navigate to another page, I would like to put an object in the flash. This is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.foo(object)}">
    <h:graphicsImage .../>
</h:commandLink>
```

And the bean method:

```
public String foo(Object o) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("key", o);
    return "target.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

I would like to do that with an h:link in xhtml without a bean method (also because I've heard that commandLink navigation is bad). I have something like this in mind, to replace above code:

```
<h:link outcome="target.xhtml">
    <h:graphicsImage .../>
    <someTag someAttr="#{facesContext.externalContext.flash.put("key", object)}"/>
</h:link>
```

Is there such a tag (someTag) that can be used like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass flash attributes like GET attributes with a `h:link`. ViewParams are not enough? This is the best way to navigate.

But you can put variables to flash scope with `c:set`. The problem is if you want to set the value dynamically after pressing the link.

Add namespace if not already present `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`

```
<c:set target="#{flash}" property="key" value="object"/>
<h:link outcome="target.xhtml">
    <h:graphicsImage .../>
</h:link>
```

Comment: That c:set thing looks promising. Can't I just put that inside the h:link to have it executed when I click the link?

Comment: You can, but it's triggered on page load, not after click the link.